# It is possible to use the guest checkout and the default country for payment by card in Ukraine

Tags: paypal

I am trying to connect a PayPal for payment in our online store using php sdk api, is it possible to use the guest payment checkout and the default country 'Ukraine' for paying with a card in Ukraine, and Russian in the interface of the payment form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set that in your seller profile:

```
Log in to your PayPal account  
Click Money at the top of the page    
Click Manage Currency 
Choose the currency to make Primary 
Click Make Primary
```

See https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/How-to-change-Paypal-default-currency-to-USD/td-p/616528